# Pyscript button

Tags: python, pyscript

I'm confused. I'm trying to run pyscript button example from - https://jeff.glass/post/7-guis-pyscript/ (first example - counter)

This is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <p id="counter-target">Some Placeholder Text</p>
        <py-button>
                def on_click(event):
                        add_one()
        </py-button>
<py-script src="myscript.py"></py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PYTHON CODE:

```
internalCount = 0
target = "counter-target"
PyScript.write(target, str(internalCount), append=False)

def add_one():
    global internalCount
    internalCount += 1
    PyScript.write(target, str(internalCount), append=False)
```

It's showing me the button (using VSC Live server), but nothing happens once clicking on it... also Visual studio code is showing me this error. I don't understand. I shouldn't import anything, right? Thanks

[image: pyscript error]

Comment: Of course you do.  If you're going to use the `PyScript` module, then you have to `import` it.  Did you install it?

Comment: @TimRoberts - PyScript loads via a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Your code should run fine in a browser. I don't think Pylance has support for PyScript.

Answer (score 2):

Define two scripts: **myscript.py**

```py
def add_one(event):
    pyscript.write("output", str(global_vars['internalCounter']), False)
    global_vars['internalCounter'] += 1
```

and **globals.py**

```py
global_vars = {"internalCounter": 1}
```

declare both of them inside your html file in py-env section:

```html
<py-env>
paths
    ./globals.py
    ./myscript.py
</py-env>
```

be sure to have identation of 4 spaces (no tab chars).
In html declare two pyscript nodes with src attributes pointing to your scripts:

```html
<py-script src='globals.py'></py-script>
<py-script src='myscript.py'></py-script>
```

change button  node as in html below (use pys-onclick) as well as make a div for output.
Complete **index.html** looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
        <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
<py-env>
paths
    ./globals.py
    ./myscript.py
</py-env>
    </head>
    <body>
        <py-script src='globals.py'></py-script>
        <py-script src='myscript.py'></py-script>   
        <div id="main">
            <p id="counter-target">Some Placeholder Text</p>
            <py-button pys-onclick="add_one">
            </py-button>
            <div id="output">Outputs here</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This way you have defined a dictionary (globals.py) where you can manipulate global variables (can define them as you like) within a session. In your myscript.py you can have functions and functionalities that you need for your app. You can in the same manner add more scripts if needed. For it to be working you should declare scripts as paths within py-env section of html and add pyscript node for each of them with src attribute pointing to .py scripts.
As you have py-button defined then your on click event is pys-onclick. I added a div for output too as you can see but it can be done differently too. There should be an id for pyscript.write() function to be operational. Regards...

Comment: At the moment the HTML attribute 'pys-onClick' is deprecated. Developers recommend to use 'py-click="myFunction()"' instead.

Comment: Also your way of defining button in the HTML is outdated. This form is correct at the moment:

<button py-click="current_time()" id="get-time" class="py-button">Get current time</button>

Source: https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/py-click.html